# How to make sure a form is valid before submitting using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a login page and have the following:

```
<div id="loginField">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="user" required></input> 
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required></input> 
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input> 
</div>
```

I made sure that the username and password fields are required. When the login is successful (for this sake, let's just say that both fields are not empty) a login disappears and another view appears. Anyway, I checked to see if the login button is pressed with JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){ 
          $('#loginField').hide();
          $('#differentView').show();});
```

The problem is that when the login button is clicked, the required attributes gets ignore and the next view is shown. How do I make sure that the required attributes are not ignored when the login button is clicked?

Comment: Use a [validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: For starters, input tags close themselves, they don't use `</input>`. And personally, I wouldn't use the required attribute, I would just do the validation myself with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The required attributes are ignored because the input elements are not inside an html form element

To use the HTML5 input valuation attributes (required, minlength... etc)

The inputs should be grouped inside a form element, and you can listen for the form submit event, that is triggered by default when the user press enter (while focus is on a field inside the form) or clicks the submit button (input or button with type="submit") that is also wrapped inside the form

HTML

```
<form id="loginForm">
  <input id="username" type="text" name="user" required />
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('#loginForm').on('submit', function (event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit page reload
        console.log('I will enter this handler only on valid form')
        $('#loginForm').hide();
        $('#differentView').show();
})();
```

Here is a basic plunker with 2 examples https://plnkr.co/edit/I0vUMSeOlrjlYYu4VofU?p=preview

- using the default html5 validation
- using Parsley

Answer (score 0):

A crude way of doing it...

```
<div id="loginField">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="user" class="required">
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="required">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</div>

$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var isReady = true;
    $('.required').each(function(){
        if (this.value === '') {
            isReady = false;
            return;
        };
    });
    if (isReady) {
        // submit form
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/). It is a javascript form validation library and it is very easy to use and you can customize it for your own means. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling onclick on button, you can put input fields into the form...

```
<form action="post" method="post" id="loginField">
    <input id="username" type="text" name="user" required></input> 
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required></input> 
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input> 
</form>
```

... and in jQuery you can handle on submit action like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loginField').on('submit', function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
      var [username password] = $(this).serializeArray(),
          username = username.value,
          password = password.value; 
      /* some validations */
  });
});
```

event.PreventDefault prevents browser from subbmiting so your page won't be refresh. serializeArray returns an array of objects (key-value) that's why you have to use .value